# There is another way for Switch case? - android

Tags: android

After two days of search I found a way to do what I need. (I am begginer with Android developement).

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.getquotes;

import java.util.Random;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    Context context;
    private String[] myString;
    private static final Random rgenerator = new Random();
    int index = 0;
    private AdView adView;
    private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
        context = this;
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ads_lin);
        layout.addView(adView);

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .addTestDevice("5B895A3CC0CA50D56506E300A4C8342B")
                .addTestDevice("D039292A1F434C999B21503D63D6FD88")

                .addTestDevice("TEST_EMULATOR").build();

        //Start loading ad in background
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;

    }

    @SuppressLint("CutPasteId")
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.phone:
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Munca",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
            Resources res = getResources();
            myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.work);
            final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quote);
            final String q = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];
            tv.setText(q);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    myString = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.work);
                    index = rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length);
                    String q = myString[index];
                    tv.setText(q);
                }
            });

            break;

        case R.id.computer:

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Inspirationale",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
            final TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quote);
            btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    myString = getResources().getStringArray(
                            R.array.inspiration);
                    index = rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length);
                    String q = myString[index];
                    tv2.setText(q);
                }
            });
            break;

        case R.id.gamepad:
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Motivare",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Button btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
            final TextView tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quote);
            btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    myString = getResources()
                            .getStringArray(R.array.motivation);
                    index = rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length);
                    String q = myString[index];
                    tv3.setText(q);
                }
            });
            break;

        case R.id.camera:
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Succes",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Button btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
            final TextView tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quote);
            btn4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    myString = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.succes);
                    index = rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length);
                    String q = myString[index];
                    tv4.setText(q);
                }
            });
            break;

        case R.id.video:
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Iubire",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Button btn5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
            final TextView tv5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quote);
            btn5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    myString = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.love);
                    index = rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length);
                    String q = myString[index];
                    tv5.setText(q);
                }
            });
            break;

        case R.id.email:
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Munca",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Button btn6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
            final TextView tv6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quote);
            btn6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    myString = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.work);
                    index = rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length);
                    String q = myString[index];
                    tv6.setText(q);
                }
            });
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (adView != null) {
            adView.resume();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        if (adView != null) {
            adView.pause();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    /** Called before the activity is destroyed. */
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Destroy the AdView.
        if (adView != null) {
            adView.destroy();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

I don't know but I am thinking there is a easier way for Switch case, this is the single method I have found.

And this is activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.getquotes.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quote"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/btn"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

    <LinearLayout1
       android:id="@+id/ads_lin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    </LinearLayout1>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Everything was working good until I added ads. When I run the app, it stop.

LOGCAT:

```
10-08 15:42:38.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16445): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-08 15:42:38.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16445): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.getquotes/com.example.getquotes.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class LinearLayout1
10-08 15:42:38.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16445):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
10-08 15:42:38.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16445):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299)
10-08 15:42:38.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16445):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
10-08 15:42:38.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16445):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
10-08 15:42:38.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16445):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-08 15:42:38.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16445):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-08 15:42:38.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16445):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
10-08 15:42:38.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16445):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-08 15:42:38.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16445):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-08 15:42:38.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16445):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
10-08 15:42:38.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16445):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
10-08 15:42:38.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16445):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-08 15:42:38.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16445): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class LinearLayout1
10-08 15:42:38.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16445):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
10-08 15:42:38.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16445):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
10-08 15:42:38.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16445):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
10-08 15:42:38.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16445):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
10-08 15:42:38.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16445):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
10-08 15:42:38.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16445):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:364)
10-08 15:42:38.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16445):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1930)
10-08 15:42:38.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16445):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:217)
10-08 15:42:38.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16445):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:110)
10-08 15:42:38.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16445):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:77)
10-08 15:42:38.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16445):    at com.example.getquotes.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
10-08 15:42:38.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16445):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5283)
10-08 15:42:38.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16445):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
10-08 15:42:38.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16445):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
10-08 15:42:38.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16445):    ... 11 more
10-08 15:42:38.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16445): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.LinearLayout1" on path: /data/app/com.example.getquotes-2.apk
10-08 15:42:38.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16445):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
10-08 15:42:38.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16445):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
10-08 15:42:38.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16445):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
10-08 15:42:38.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16445):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:558)
10-08 15:42:38.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16445):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:649)
10-08 15:42:38.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16445):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
10-08 15:42:38.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16445):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:666)
10-08 15:42:38.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16445):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
10-08 15:42:38.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16445):    ... 24 more
```

I don't know from where comes the error.

Comment: <LinearLayout1
       android:id="@+id/ads_lin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    </LinearLayout1> whats this ?? remove 1

Comment: What do you think about switch case? There is a method easier to generate random text from array?

Comment: wt you say just cleare that

Comment: @BiancaRaysa : This question has nothing to do with switch/case and is primarily about the fact you were getting a `ClassNotFoundException`. I voted to close as it's highly unlikely the question will be of any future use to other Stack Overflow users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says

```
ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.LinearLayout1"
```

that `LinearLayout1` does not exits. Remove the `1` for both the tags

Comment: this shold in comment not need to in answers'

Comment: @LazyCoder This is answer, not a question and also it is not a query to add it in comment. So it can be here.